# How to access the User object from Account object, via the Contact object. Error: No such column 'Users' on entity 'Contact'

Tags: apex, soql, contact, person-accounts, user-record

I would like to write a `SOQL` query which goes from `Account > Contact > User(s)`

Something like this:

```
[SELECT PersonContactId, PersonContact.Users, PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE ...]
```

But I get this error:

> No such column 'Users' on entity 'Contact'.

I also get this error:

> No such column 'PersonContact' on entity 'Account'

But the `Account` object has a field called `PersonContactId` with a relationship name `PersonContact`

[image]

And the `Contact` object has a child relationship named: `Users`

[image]

So therefore, I should be able to do `PersonContact.Users`

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get the `User` collection when querying `Account`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child relationships are only accessible by a subQuery, which means

```
SELECT 
  LastName, 
  (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Users
  )
FROM Contact
WHERE ...
```

This kind of subQueries can only happen on the top-most level of your query, hence you won't be able to get to that level from Account. Try reworking your query from Contact instead, something like

```
SELECT 
  LastName, 
  (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Users
  )
FROM Contact 
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT PersonContactId 
  FROM Account 
  WHERE...)
```